# How to extra EXTRA_PAIRING_KEY after Android devices paired

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I would like to use `EXTRA_PAIRING_KEY` to implement the AES encryption for Bluetooth massaging in Android platform, so I need to extract it after both Android paired. Can I use the code like `device.getName()` and `device.getAddress()` to get `EXTRA_PAIRING_KEY`?

Comment: That is used for an intent to establish the pairing. You cannot extract the key for Bluetooth encryption. What is it that you are ultimately trying to do?

Comment: Now I created a peer to peer Bluetooth messaging function in Android, which the text message does not transmitted by any third party.

The next step I would like to do is establish an encryption for the text message by using AES, which use the same same key to encrypt and decrypt message. But key exchange is the problem, which I cannot find a safty method to exchange the key between both side of Android device.

So I conside to use EXTRA_PAIRING_KEY as the key to encrypt and decrypt the text message, which was exchanged when establish the pairing.

Comment: If you create a secure RFCOMM socket it will encrypt and decrypt for you.